# Why i'm getting a 404 for PNG in mod_pagespeed

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mod-pagespeed

I have a small problem with the **mod_pagespeed** module in Wordpress on Apache server. I'm getting a 404 related only to **PNG** images, but not always, not for all and not even for the same images. Automatically, sometimes you see, sometimes not instead.

When it happens, i try to disable the mod_pagespeed inserting `?ModPagespeed=off`, and magically PNG images appear correctly.

Always when it happens, hanging on the URL `?ModPagespeed=on&ModPagespeedFilters=` you see the PNG images.

Again you see the PNG also enabling a filter at a time with for example:

`?ModPagespeed=on&ModPagespeedFilters=extend_cache`.

At this point, i think that it might be a problem of `RewriteCond` in `.htaccess` file. So, i put the exception:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !pagespeed`

under:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

But still doesn't work. Do i also hang it with the basic rules of Wordpress? That are the follow:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

What do you think?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

Your RewriteCond:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !pagespeed
```

has two problems with it.

First, QUERY_STRING is a separate variable from REQUEST_URI, and so your REQUEST_URI doesn't in fact contain pagespeed.

Second, it's case sensitive.

So I believe what you meant was

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} Pagespeed
```

Note if you're unsure of the case of the string, or if it could be either, you can use the [NC] flag on the end of RewriteCond to indicate that it's case insensitive.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I simply inserted the code as suggested in mod_pagespeed FAQ. You could find it in this page:

[link] (https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/faq)

So, i don't know why it shouldn't work with that.